# Is it possible to change branch background color by status of the branch in vim-airline?

Tags: vim, vim-airline

I would like to see some indication in vim-airline git branch section if there is uncommitted changes in it - like color could be different and if there are changes there would be ± sign next to branch. I can't find anything related from vim-airline documentation/issues, any tips how this could be done?

This is how the same thing is configured in my terminal:

[image: ZSH way to do it]

Comment: not possible currently. We only have the [notexists symbol](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/blob/master/doc/airline.txt#L436-L437), but nothing if the working repository is dirty.

Comment: Please feel free to add this as feature request to the vim-airline bug tracker

Comment: latest airline supports this now.